# Get Annotation using TestNG 7.0.0

Tags: java, maven, testng

I had this line of code using TestNG 6.11:

```
Annotation[] annotations =  (Annotation[]) myResult.getMethod().getMethod().getDeclaredAnnotations();
```

Now this code does not compile on Maven 7.0.0-Beta1.

What to do?

Error:

```
cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   method getMethod() [ERROR] location: interface org.testng.ITestNGMethod
```

Comment: I meant TestNG = 7.0.0 Beta-1, not Maven. Error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getMethod()
[ERROR] location: interface org.testng.ITestNGMethod

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @TalAngel Please include that error in your question also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ITestNGMethod#getMethod()`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/6.11/org/testng/ITestNGMethod.html#getMethod--) was *deprecated* and thus removed in later version, you will have to use `getConstructorOrMethod()` instead.

```
Annotation[] annotations =  (Annotation[]) iITestNGMethod.getConstructorOrMethod()
                                                         .getDeclaredAnnotations();
```

See [this](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.testng/testng/7.0.0-beta1) doc of *TestNG 7.0.0-beta1*.